# MySql: Creating rows in a new table for each existing row in a different table

Tags: mysql

Hey: I'm trying to do a MySql migration, but Im very new to the language, and the syntax is fustrating me. The basic idea of what I want to do is:

-Get all of the events in table 1

-For each of these events, insert a row into the ticketing_information table (these have an automatically generated id)

-Set the event's ticketing_information_id to match the id in the newly generated row

(then the same again for tables 2 and 3)

So I have ideas about how the various steps might work, but I'm not sure how you combine various expressions in sql (is there a foreach? how do i pick the specific row that I just made, if I know nothing unique about it to identify it?)

Comment: Ok get the idea from table1 but where to get the rest of the data for ticketing_information  from?

Comment: Although the syntax might be a bit bewildering at first, MySQL's SQL is very similar to the sort of SQL you'd use in other databases, so it's an investment that will pay dividends in the future. Do you have a good reference for SQL in general?

Comment: the ticketing_information's data will just be default values for now. And no, I don't really know any sql

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use this syntax :

```
INSERT INTO "table1" ("column1", "column2", ...)
SELECT "column3", "column4", ...
FROM "table2";
```

With something like that :

```
INSERT INTO ticketing_information1 (column_name)
SELECT other_column_name
FROM table1
```

It will insert a new entry for each value selected in the ticketing_information1 table.

Answer (score 0):

So I came across this while writing a migration for a laravel polymorphic relation and Franck's answer is close but misses the part about updating the local key to match the new row.

My original migration following Frank's answer was

```
INSERT INTO `block_anchor_blocks` (`anchor_slug`, `label`)
SELECT `title`, `content`
FROM `blocks` where `type` = "anchor";
```

If the reference to the original block lived on the anchor_block as a belongs to this would have been easy, I could have just done

```
INSERT INTO `block_anchor_blocks` (`anchor_slug`, `label`, `block_id`)
SELECT `title`, `content`, `id`
FROM `blocks` where `type` = "anchor";
```

But this was not the case the polymorphic relation lives within the blocks table, so I ended up with the following code:

```
/* Create The New Table */
CREATE TABLE `block_anchor_blocks` (
   `id` CHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY,
   `anchor_slug` VARCHAR(255),
   `label` VARCHAR(255),
   `created_at` TIMESTAMP,
   `updated_at` TIMESTAMP
);


/* Build the polymorphic fields on the table we're refactoring */
ALTER TABLE `blocks`
ADD `blockable_id` CHAR(36);
ALTER TABLE `blocks`
ADD `blockable_type` VARCHAR(255);

/* Generate the UUID to use when creating an entry in the new table. */
UPDATE `blocks`
SET `blockable_id`=(SELECT UUID()),`blockable_type`="Acme\\Shared\\Entities\\Blocks\\AnchorBlock"
WHERE `type` = "anchor";

/* Finally we Insert using the ID we generated in the last step */
INSERT INTO `block_anchor_blocks` (`anchor_slug`, `label`, `id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
SELECT `title`, `content`, `blockable_id`, NOW(), NOW()
FROM `blocks` where `type` = "anchor";
```

hopefully, this helps anyone else trying to refactor a large single table into multiple joined tables.

Answer (score -2):

Are you sure you want to do this?

Why do tables 2 and 3 need the same info as table 1?  The only reason I can see to have the table 1 primary key in tables 2 and 3 would be to express a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship.  Otherwise, you might consider just adding those columns to table 1 if it's a one-to-one relationship.

Tables 2 and 3 have to have their own primary keys.  This is first normal form.  You should be familiar with that that means.

Comment: tables 1, 2 and 3 are each different types of event, totally independent from each other. They do, however, each need a "ticketing-information" entity. Because it is possible that 2 events of different types have the same ID, I chose to use the ticketing information id for the link between the events and the ticketing info

Comment: Different events should have different primary keys, but they can refer to the ticketing info with a foreign key.

Comment: I needed to do this in order to write a migration to push data that lived in table 1 into tables 2-5 depending on type. I was pushing data from a single table into a laravel polymorphic relation. This is a vital step to migrate the data before dropping the columns from the original table.